# I am getting error while logging to docker desktop. Post "https://hub.docker.com/v2/access-tokens/desktop-generate"

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am getting the following error when I am trying to login:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLVxw.png)
Post "https://hub.docker.com/v2/access-tokens/desktop-generate": net/http: invalid header field value "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" for key X-Docker-Desktop-Id

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: Nope. I didn't find the solution and the issue still exists. Do tell me if you fix it.